# Access denied on selecting database in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I can't connect to a database in VB.net. If I select a database and press "ok" it says `Access is denied`.

I tried restarting sqlexpress but still doesn't work. I chose MS sql server sqlClient as the Datasource.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't create a database. It only connects to an existing database. But for the database you have, should check that you can connect via Management Studio.

Comment: Voting to close, your question is too broad, try to debug and find more specific questions to answer about what might be wrong. Also, "my VB.net" makes no sense.

Comment: Ooo sorry, yes I have existing database but I can't connect on it

Comment: If you want to create a data file that can be attached to a SQL Server Express instance on demand then you add a new item to your project in the Solution Explorer and select Service-based Database as the item template.

Comment: i also tried it, still says Access Denied